# Bad interaction between mdwtools' syntax package and graphicx

Tags: graphics, mdwtools

I'm writing a document where I want to both include some image via `graphicx`'s `\includegraphics` and display some BNF grammars using the `syntax` package of `mdwtools`, however I receive an error of `undefined control sequence` when I try to use them together *with some filenames*.

A minimal example that fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{logo_uniud_black}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this I get the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
\filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base 
                                                  {#1}
l.8 \includegraphics{logo_uniud_black}

   [omissis]

! Undefined control sequence.
\filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base 
                                                  {#1}
l.8 \includegraphics{logo_uniud_black}

(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
```

Commenting out `\usepackage{syntax}` fixes the problem. Also using a filename that doesn't contain underscore works, so that this code doesn't fail:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{logouniudblack}

\end{document}
```

Why do I get this error and how is it related to the underscore in the filename?
Is there a way to fix it without renaming all the files I have to include?

---

Edit:

Actually it seems like even section names with underscore create problems, so that `\include`s raise similar errors, for example with the source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\include{sintassi_astratta}

\end{document}
```

I get these errors:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools/syntax.sty) (./bad_doc.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \@empty \def \MessageBreak...
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                     \endgroup 
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

! Argument of \reserved@b has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

Runaway argument?
{\usc@builtindischyphen }\futurelet \@let@token \@ifnch astratta.aux
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@b was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

(./sintassi.tex)
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

! Too many }'s.
\@filef@und ...\@let@token \let \discretionary {-}
                                                  {}{}\discretionary {-}{}{}...
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./sintassi.tex)
Runaway text?
\@setckpt{sintassi\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \kern .06em\vbox {\hrule \ETC.
! File ended while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

! Unbalanced write command.
<write> ... \@setckpt {sintassi_astratta}\@charlb 

l.7 \include{sintassi_astratta}

(./bad_doc.aux
Runaway argument?
{sintassi\protect \global \let \OT 1\textunderscore \unhbox \voidb@x \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@input was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.5 

! Missing { inserted.
l.7 ...or immediate help   \endgroup {}\def \par }

)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.9 \end{document}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.9 \end{document}

! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.9 \end{document}

 )
```

If I'm not mistaken instead of looking for `sintassi_astratta.tex` it is looking for `sintassi.tex`. It seems like `syntax` is redefining the underscore in some way that breaks everything.

Comment: Yes, `syntax` makes the underscore active; if you *really* need it and also need underscores in file names, say `\input{\detokenize{sintassi_astratta}}` and similarly for `\includegraphics` or `\include`. For a better solution, an example of how you're using `syntax` and knowing if you need the active underscore is needed.

Comment: @egreg I believe I don't need `_` as active character. Should I just change it `\catcode` to `11` after loading `syntax`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `syntax` package has a `nounderscore` option; you then need to use `\_` for compound names.

If you prefer to have `_` meaning `\_` outside of math mode, then use

```
\input{\detokenize{file_name}}
```

and similarly for `\include` or `\includegraphics`. So

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{logo_uniud_black}

\end{document}
```

will work as well as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{\detokenize{logo_uniud_black}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your example shouldn't `nounderscore` be used as option to `syntax`?

Comment: @Bakuriu yes:-)

Answer (score 4):

use `\string_` for an underscore

```
\includegraphics{/tmp/logo\string_uniud\string_black}
```